# How can i kept the whole text visible in edittext?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext, scrollview

I am trying to build a simple note app. And i would like to add checkbox functional.

I keep note part and checkbox recyclerview in scrollview to make it a one scrollable element. But when there are too many text in note or to many lines in checklist i can't see the whole note text. Just cant scroll to top of note. How can i fix it?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtHiJ.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/add_note_note_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/add_note_options"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_note_options">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/add_note_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:hint="@string/note_hint"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/add_note_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_note_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_note_checkbox_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/checkbox"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_check_deactive"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_note_reusable_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/reusable"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_reusable_deactive"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/add_note_checkbox_item"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_note_progress_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/progress"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_progress_deactive"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/add_note_reusable_item"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_note_ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="@android:string/ok"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The xml attribute `android:maxLines` may help, try to google for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:layout_marginTop="80dp"` in `LinearLayout` , change as require .

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try just this way may help you

```
android:minLines="2" 
android:maxLines="100"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"


<EditText android:id="@+id/et"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@null"
 android:gravity="top|left"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
android:maxLines="100"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
></EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

**please try to this**

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="set limit what ever you need set max line"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```